# Netflix video does not autoplay on chrome

Tags: selenium, selenium-chromedriver, html5-video

I am trying to autoplay Netflix video using Selenium on chrome on a Linux machine. I open the video using the following url: `https://www.netflix.com/title/<video_id>`. Normally, the video starts playing once the page loads. However, with selenium, the video page opens up and a play button comes up. The video does not play until I click button manually. Is there a workaround such as opening chrome with specific flags to disable this?

Answer (score 0):

One workaround that I found was to mute the Netflix video. I think this has to do with the new updates to chrome wherein video can only be autoplayed if they are muted.

https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/09/autoplay-policy-changes